# Combining R shiny and R script

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, shiny

I have a R script which takes an excel, process the excel with sheet having same headers and the output renders in a dataframe.

I have created an interface using R shiny where user can upload an excel file.

Now, when the file is uploaded by the user in the shiny, it must be processed in the R script.

Can anyone help to do this connection?
**Very important:**   ***data and format must take the uploaded file***

**R script code:**

````
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)  
library(tidyxl)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- tidyxl::xlsx_cells(#path for my file) #
formats <- tidyxl::xlsx_formats(#path for my file)

#select column row character & sheet which are bold
sheet_data <- data[
  data$local_format_id %in% which(formats$local$font$bold)
  & !is.na(data$character), c("row", "character", 'sheet')] 

#rename columns
colnames(sheet_data) <- c("rowNumber", "content", 'sheetRow') 

#count sheets have all the 5 columns
grouped_sheets <- sheet_data %>%
  group_by(sheetRow, rowNumber, .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(check = str_trim(stringr::str_to_lower(content)) %in% c("qty", "item", "description", "rate", "unit")) %>%
  summarise(check = sum(check)) 

#selecting sheets having all the 5 columns and output the sheet Names
anchor1 <- grouped_sheets %>% filter(check == 5) %>% select(sheetRow) 



#empty dataframe to append 
z <- data.frame() 

#loop with the selected sheets 
for(sheet in anchor1$sheetRow){
  
  #identify bold caracters 
  bold <- data[
    data$local_format_id %in% which(formats$local$font$bold)
    & !is.na(data$character)
    & data$sheet == sheet, c("row", "character")
  ]
  
  #rename colnames
  colnames(bold) <- c("rownumber", "content")  
  
  grouped_rows <- bold %>%
    group_by(rownumber) %>%
    mutate(check = str_trim(stringr::str_to_lower(content)) %in% c("qty", "item", "description", "rate", "unit")) %>%
    summarise(check = sum(check))
  
  anchor <- grouped_rows %>% filter(check >= 4) %>% select(rownumber)
    
  bold_rows <- grouped_rows %>%
    select(rownumber) %>%
    mutate(a_row = rownumber - as.integer(anchor['rownumber'])) %>%
    select(a_row) %>%
    filter(a_row > 0)
    
  excel <- read.xlsx(#path for my file, 
                     sheetName = sheet,
                     startRow = as.integer(anchor['rownumber']))[c('Item', 'Description', 'Unit', 'Qty', 'Rate')]
  
  excel[,"Type"] <- NA #new column type
  excel[bold_rows$a_row, "Type"] <- "BOLD"
  
  
  a = excel[rowSums(is.na(excel)) != ncol(excel), ]#removing empty rows(Na)remove na after bold
  a=a[- grep("Carried", a$Qty),] #removing rows having carried to...
  a=a[is.na(as.numeric(a$Unit)),] #removing rows where unit is numeric
  a=a[- grep("Brought forward from", a$Description),]#removing rows having brought forward
  e=a[- grep("Collection for", a$Description),]#removing rows having collection
  
  
  e[,"IsItem"] <- FALSE #new column IsItem
  e[,"IsPreamble"] <- FALSE
  e[grep("Preambles",e$Description,ignore.case = TRUE),"IsPreamble"]<- TRUE
  
  for (i in 1:length(e$Item)) {
    if(!is.na(e$Description[i]) && !is.na(e$Item[i]) && !is.na(e$Rate[i])&& 
       !is.na(e$Unit[i])&& !is.na(e$Qty[i])){
      e$IsItem[i] <- TRUE
    }
    if(e$IsPreamble[i] == TRUE && !is.na(e$Type[i])){
      e$IsPreamble[i] <- TRUE
    }else{
      e$IsPreamble[i] <- FALSE
    }
  }
  
  v<-read.xlsx("~/Section/allSection.xlsx", 
               sheetName = "Sheet1")
  
  e[,"IsSection"] <- FALSE #new column IsSection
  pattern <- paste0(trimws(v$Item),collapse = '|')#trim with whitespace and concatenate vector after converting to vector
  e[grepl(pattern,e$Description,ignore.case = TRUE),"IsSection"]<- TRUE
  
  e[,"IsTitle"] <- FALSE
  e[,"IsInstruction"] <- FALSE
  
  for (i in 1:length(e$Description)) {
    if(e$IsSection[i] == TRUE && !is.na(e$Type[i])){
      e$IsSection[i] <- TRUE
    }else{
      e$IsSection[i] <- FALSE
    }
    if(!is.na(e$Description[i]) && is.na(e$Unit[i]) && is.na(e$Qty[i]) &&
       is.na(e$Rate[i]) && !is.na(e$Type[i]) && e$IsItem[i] == 'FALSE' && e$IsPreamble[i] == 'FALSE' 
       && e$IsSection[i] == 'FALSE'){
      e$IsTitle[i] <- TRUE
    }
    if(!is.na(e$Description[i]) && is.na(e$Unit[i]) && is.na(e$Qty[i]) &&
       is.na(e$Rate[i]) && is.na(e$Type[i]) && e$IsItem[i] == 'FALSE' && e$IsPreamble[i] == 'FALSE' 
       && e$IsSection[i] == 'FALSE' && e$IsTitle[i] == 'FALSE'){
      e$IsInstruction[i] <- TRUE
    }
    
  }
  
  e[, "Sheet_Name"] <- sheet
  z = rbind(z, e)
  
}


df = subset(z, select = -c(Item, IsPreamble))```


After running the r script, the user must be able to input 2 columns on the interface and save the final output.
````

Comment: I am removing `pandas` tag bcz it has nothing to do with `pandas`

Comment: You can integrate the code into your shiny app or convert the script into a function, which you then call when processing is needed.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik can you help when to call the function exactly?

Comment: You would call the function from shiny at a point where you want the files to be imported and processed.